# YouTube V3 API C# - ResumeAsync() The operation was Canceled

Tags: c#, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm having some problems with the YouTube API using the ResumeAsync() method.

Here is my code...

```
        YouTubeService youtube = await AuthService.AuthenticateYouTubeAsync(auth);
        ResumableUpload<Video, Video> vidUploadReq = null;

        var video = new Video();
        video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
        video.Snippet.Title = videoToUpload.Title;
        video.Snippet.Description = videoToUpload.Description;
        video.Snippet.Tags = videoToUpload.Tags;
        video.Snippet.CategoryId = videoToUpload.CategoryID;
        video.Status = new VideoStatus();
        video.Status.PrivacyStatus = videoToUpload.PrivacyStatus;
        var filePath = videoToUpload.LocalFilePath;

        // Get chunk size and make sure it's valid
        int chunkSizeBytes = defaultChunkSizeKB * 1024;

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            vidUploadReq = youtube.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
            vidUploadReq.ProgressChanged += videoUploadRequest_ProgressChanged;
            vidUploadReq.ResponseReceived += videoUploadRequest_ResponseReceived;
            vidUploadReq.ChunkSize = chunkSizeBytes;

            await vidUploadReq.UploadAsync(token);
        }
```

Where does resuming fit into this?

Am I expected to serialize the ResumableUpload object for when I restart the application?

It seems like I need to preserve UploadUri for next time, and next time, set this UploadUri and StreamLength properties. However, both of these fields are PRIVATE in the API.

Is there a better way other than using reflection to set these private properties?

Comment: Check this SO question [21321878](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321878/youtube-c-sharp-api-v3-how-do-you-resume-an-interrupted-upload) if it can help you :)

Comment: Yes I have seen this thread before I posted. However, it doesn't answer my question. My question is pretty much "Is there a better way other than using reflection to set these private properties?"... Your link gives an example where reflection works. This is NOT a good way to solve this problem at all. It defeats the purpose of information hiding principles of O-O programming. Do you see now?

Comment: The link 'gets around' the problem, does it does not hide the fact that this IS a problem.

Answer (score 1):

As of version 1.14, the **Google API v3 .NET Client Library** contains the capability to save the **UploadUri** during a ResumableUpload session and to later use that **UploadUri** to resume the upload in the event of a program restart.

There are two ResumableUpload examples in https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client-samples that demonstrate the use of **.ResumeAsync** with an additional parameter of the previously saved **UploadUri**. An **UploadSessionData** event called at the start of the upload provides the **UploadUri** to the client program so it can save it to persistent storage for retrieval upon a program restart.